# Is it possible to add a security trim that filters by user groups?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, security

In my left hand side bar I have 3 links to downloads- one for each of three different companies. I need each company to log in and see only the one link to their companies downloads - not all 3 links for each company.

In the code I was hoping to put a security trim around each link that only ran the code if the user is a member of that companies group.

Is this possible?

i.e.

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl
 ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl1" **Group="Company1"** runat="server">

'Link to Company one downloads' </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

If not is there a good workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Sharepoint 2010 Server (not Foundation) you can put these links into three different content editor web parts and define target audiences for them. 
http://blog.sharepointlearn.com/2011/02/20/use-audience-targeting-to-filter-who-sees-an-assessment-in-sharepoint/

Comment: That's great thank you - I can even spend some time on the UI for once!

Answer (score 0):

Use Audience targeting in the navigation.

Comment: This is a fair workaround, but let's not mistake comparing Audience targeting to security, because it's not.